# Why [style] doesn't update

Tags: angular

I have this code **app.component.ts**

```
ngOnInit() {

      let width600 = this.commonService.width600();
      let width380_768 = this.commonService.width380_768();
      let width768 = this.commonService.width768();
      let width992 = this.commonService.width992();
      let width1200 = this.commonService.width1200();

  function handler(mediaQueryList) {
     if (width380_768.matches) {
        this.maxWidth = 200;
     } 
     if (width768.matches) {
        this.maxWidth = 500;

     } 
     if (width992.matches) {
        this.maxWidth = 800;
     } 
     if (width1200.matches) {
        this.maxWidth = 1000;
     } 
  }

 window.matchMedia('(max-width: 767px), (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px), (min-width: 1200px)').addListener(handler);

}
```

When width of screen is changed then fired one of instriction **if** and `this.maxWidth` is chenged on the another value.

This code **app.component.html**

```
<div class="content" [style.maxWidth.px]="maxWidth">
</div>
```

It doesn't work although maxWidth is changed.
I think it doesn't update DOM element what why it doesn't work.
I tried to do it with (click) and all works.

Comment: Where and how is `maxWith` changed? Did you verify that is actually changed?

Comment: Please don't do stuff like this. Try to solve styling specific stuff with css and not with angular. And if you really really need to do it with angular, don't use the style property and work with css classes.

Comment: Yep, I ran with console.log(), and when width is changed then console.log() fired. I think DOM doesn't update and i think how update it

Comment: Thanks, with native JS all works but can angular 2 do anything? Untidy the job in the angular 2 about css. It is so difficult

Comment: You should bind context like `handler.bind(this)` and use ChangeDetectorRef to detect changes

Comment: thanks I understand. I am doing it by dint of native JS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use ChangeDetectionRef to detect changes

```
import { ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';

export class AppComponent {
  maxWidth: any = 900;
  constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    window.matchMedia('(max-width: 767px), (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px), (min-width: 1200px)').addListener(this.handler.bind(this));
  }

  handler(mediaQueryList) {
    this.maxWidth = 200;
    this.cd.detectChanges();
  }
}
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/f0M1h8uq2s8FisSr7tPw?p=preview)**

or run your handler inside angular2 zone like:

```
import { Component, NgZone } from '@angular/core';

export class AppComponent {
  maxWidth: any = 900;
  constructor(private ngZone: NgZone) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    window.matchMedia('(max-width: 767px), (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px), (min-width: 1200px)').addListener((mediaQueryList)=>{
       console.log(NgZone.isInAngularZone());
       this.ngZone.run(() => this.handler(mediaQueryList));
    });
  }

  handler(mediaQueryList) {
    this.maxWidth = 200;
  }
}
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/A4NY2AvOOo4KTl4MEu7i?p=preview)**

Comment: Thank you it's pretty well.